# How to copy webpack builds when publishing using .NET Framework

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, .net-4.0, azure-cloud-services

I have an older project that uses ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI, runs on .NET Framework, and gets published to an Azure Cloud Service. I'm trying to migrate to React and would like to avoid adding the webpack build as a file on the .csproj. I have managed to get build steps that run `npm run build` to generate the output, but the built files do not get added to the published package when I try to publish.

In a .NET 5 application when you use the React/SPA template the .csproj file has something like the following:

```xml
    <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
        <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

        <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
            <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
                <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
                <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
                <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            </ResolvedFileToPublish>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

I think I understand what this is doing, but I'm having trouble coming up with an analog that works with .NET Framework. When I run it just like this the commands don't even run. I'm guessing the `ComputeFilesToPublish` target does not get called on these older-style projects. I've tried running it using `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` of both `Build` and `Publish`, and when I do that I can see from the logs that `npm install` and `npm run build` are being called, but the files are not copied to the publish directory (in this case `csx`).

What can I do in the `.csproj` to get my build files pulled into the publish package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the build targets for a .NET 5 Azure Web App are different from a .NET Framework Azure Cloud Service. Here was the secret sauce I needed:

```xml
  <Target Name="BuildRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Importance="normal" Text="Running npm install as a Pre-build step" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Message Importance="normal" Text="Running npm run build (compile webpack) as a Pre-Build step" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="CollectFilesFromContent">
    <!--On publish, this will pull any files in the ClientApp\dist folder that were built by webpack. These files need to be in the published package.-->
    <Message Importance="normal" Text="Collecting webpack bundle for publish" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks. But I was wondering.. I have defined the npm install and npm run build outside of the project project folder, but in a "before build" script. Do you know if there's a exectuable command I could use instead of the "PublishRunWebpack" ?